# Provide custom parameters ($npm_config_) to npm scripts on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, npm, npm-scripts

I have npm scripts in the `package.json`, I would like to provide custom parameter from the command line. I found many stackoverflow questions and answers but none of them works. I tried this solution:

```
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "echo $npm_config_foo && echo done"
  },
```

When I run the command:

```
$ npm run foo --foo=test

> echo $npm_config_foo && echo done

$npm_config_foo
done
```

As you can see, it does not echo `test`.

This is my configuration:

```
- OS: Windows
- Terminal: GitBash
- npm version: 7.14.0
```

I tried this, on Linux and it works. This is related to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is Great but does not work if the Repo is used by both Windows and Linux Users. If so than I recommend to use cross-var (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var)

Just add it into the beginning of the script (after you added it to your dependencies)

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "cross-var echo $npm_config_foo && echo done",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use % instead of $.

```
  "scripts": {
     "foo": "echo %npm_config_foo% && echo done",
  },
```